# Session Id unexpectedly changing in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish

We have a JSF application.  There is one ajax call that hits a JSP page.  We have no problems when the application is hosted by Jetty.  When the application is hosted by Glassfish we have a problem when using Chrome or Firefox (IE works fine).

The problem is this.  The JSP page seems to be getting posted in a separate session and so session data is missing.  I can demonstrate this as follows: on the server side log session id when they hit JSF page, log session id when they perform the action that is handled by the JSP page.  On Jetty and Glassfish with IE both session ids match.  On Glassfish with Chrome or Firefox session ids do not match.

Interesting enough if I look at the web developer view of chrome both requests have same, and correct session id.  I have attached these below.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?  For background, this page is using the JumpLoader applet and the jsp page on the backend handles the file uploads.

**HTTP Communication as recorded by Chrome.
Initial visit to page.**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/site/page.jsf
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:248
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=fd9672a56d316006bcba33bbc0e0
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/site/page.jsf
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:keepAlive:resetKeepAlive
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
keepAlive:resetKeepAlive:keepAlive:resetKeepAlive
keepAlive:keepAlive
javax.faces.ViewState:6933564973876914096:3857165940441139007

Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:500
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 04 Jun 2013 15:42:26 GMT
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
```

**JCP handled post.**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/site/page.jsf
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:418
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=fd9672a56d316006bcba33bbc0e0
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/site/page.jsf
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:jumploaderMessages:updateJumploaderMessages
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
jumploaderMessages:updateJumploaderMessages:jumploaderMessages:updateJumploaderMessages
fileName:My Pictures.zip
response:Error:Exception e = java.lang.NullPointerException
jumploaderMessages:jumploaderMessages
javax.faces.ViewState:6933564973876914096:3857165940441139007

Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:1144
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 04 Jun 2013 15:43:14 GMT
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
```